# Swiperjs in web component return duplicated items

Tags: javascript, web-component, swiper.js, google-web-designer

I'm creating a custom carousel web component with using Swiperjs as part of the element.

The quantity of items is dynamic, it is depend on the value that get from the web component attribute sliderBgImage and sliderCopyImage.

Then, it will loop thru the array and implementing the items with Swiper.js carousel library.
Hope someone can advise on this, thank you!

[image]

index.html

```
    <div style="width:320px;height:480px;">
        <verticalsliderBgImage="banner1.png,banner2.png" sliderCopyImage="copy1.png,copy2.png" sliderlanding1="http://www.google.com" sliderlanding2="http://www.test.com" sliderlanding3="http://www.test.com" sliderlanding4="" sliderlanding5="" autoplay="true" speed="2000" pagingColor="3eff8a"></vertical>
    </div>
    <script src="vertical.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets/4671853/swiper.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

Vertical.js

```
template.innerHTML = `
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./swiper.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="./vertical.css"/><div id="mainContainer"><div class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper"></div><div class="swiper-pagination"></div></div></div>`;

class Vertical extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  handleSliderClick = () => {
    let slides = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      const slide = slides[i];

      slide.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const getslide = slide.getAttribute("data");
        const landing = getslide.slice(-1);
        Enabler.exitOverride(getslide, this.getAttribute(landing));
      });
    }
  };

  setPaginateColor = () => {
    const activeBullet = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(
      ".swiper-pagination-bullet-active"
    );
    if (activeBullet) {
      activeBullet.style.backgroundColor = `#${this.getAttribute(
        "pagingColor"
      )}`;
    }
  };

  darkNav = () => {
    var slides = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
    var copies = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".copies");

    for (let i = 0, c = 0; i < slides.length, c < copies.length; i++, c++) {
      const slide = slides[i];
      const copy = copies[c];

      if (
        slide.classList.contains("swiper-slide-active") ||
        slide.classList.contains("swiper-slide-duplicate-active")
      ) {
        slide.classList.add("bubbleslide");
        this.setPaginateColor();
        setTimeout(() => {
          copy.classList.add("slide-top");
        }, 200);
      } else {
        slide.classList.remove("bubbleslide");
        copy.classList.remove("slide-top");
      }
    }
  };

  setSwiper = (ele) => {
    const setAutoplay = this.getAttribute("autoplay");
    const setSpeed = this.getAttribute("speed");

    var swiper = new Swiper(ele, {
      autoplay: {
        delay: setSpeed,
      },
      direction: "vertical",
      pagination: {
        el: this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".swiper-pagination"),
        clickable: true,
      },
      loop: true,
      on: {
        slideChangeTransitionStart: this.darkNav,
      },
    });

    this.setPaginateColor();

    if (setAutoplay === "true" || setAutoplay === "TRUE") {
      swiper.autoplay.start();
    } else {
      swiper.autoplay.stop();
    }

    this.handleSliderClick();

    setTimeout(() => {
      swiper.autoplay.stop();
    }, 30000);
  };


  static get observedAttributes() {
    return [
      "brandLogo",
      "sliderBgImage",
      "sliderCopyImage",
      "pagingColor",
      "autoplay",
      "speed",
    ];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    var bgImgs = this.getAttribute("sliderBgImage").split(",");
    var copyImgs = this.getAttribute("sliderCopyImage").split(",");
    var items = [];

    // clean up each item
    for (let i = 0; i < bgImgs.length; i++) {
      let val1 = bgImgs[i];
      let val2 = copyImgs[i];
      let obj = {
        bg: val1,
        tag: val2,
      };
      items.push(obj);
    }
   }

  connectedCallback() {
    var bgImgs = this.getAttribute("sliderBgImage").split(",");
    var copyImgs = this.getAttribute("sliderCopyImage").split(",");
    var items = [];

    // clean up each item
    for (let i = 0; i < bgImgs.length; i++) {
      let val1 = bgImgs[i];
      let val2 = copyImgs[i];
      let obj = {
        bg: val1,
        tag: val2,
      };
      items.push(obj);
    }

    let checkItem = null;
    const swiperContainer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".swiper-wrapper");
    const swiperMain = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".swiper-container");

    items.map((v, k) => {
      let html = `<div class="swiper-slide slide${k + 1}" data="slide${
        k + 1
      }" style="background-image:url('${v.bg}')"><div class="copies copy${
        k + 1
      }" style="background-image:url('${v.tag}')"></div></div>`;
      checkItem++;
      return (swiperContainer.innerHTML += html);
    });

    let check = setInterval(() => {
      if (checkItem === items.length) {
        this.setSwiper(swiperMain);
        clearInterval(check);
      }
    }, 500);
  }

}

export default Vertical;
```

Comment: add plenty of console.log statements. At first glance your ``for`` condition ``i < slides.length, c < copies.length`` looks iffy

Comment: wondering if there any good solution? 
@Danny'365CSI'Engelman  the for loop condition is working fine

Comment: Your code is way too long for people to understand, that is why you don't get any answers.
Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)